# Using cURL --data in C#

Tags: c#, curl

I want to use the following cURL command from python in C#, but I haven't found any way to do so.

```
$ curl --data "type=AUTH&code=CODE" https://example.com
```

I hope you can help me out with this issue I'm facing.

Comment: If you insist on using cUrl, look into [Process.Start()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2) - however using the .Net builtin methods like [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) would integrate way easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Filburt you can use HttpClient to post data using C#

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.com");
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("type", "AUTH"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", "CODE")
        });
        var result = await client.PostAsync("", content);
        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
    }
```